# Why I can't insert a picture into database?

Tags: sql

I have a table with

```
create table pictures(
    pic_ID int,
    picture blob,
    primary key (pic_ID)
);
```

I use `INSERT INTO pictures VALUES (1, load_file('/home/hai/Pictures/icon.jpeg'));`
and then `select * from pictures;` displays this

[image: result]

Why it has **NULL** in my picture column ?

Comment: If you are using `input type='file'` for uploading an image then you must have  `enctype='multipart/form-data'` attribute in form tag.                                                                              eg- <form 
 action='' method='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>

Answer (score 6):

Standard MySQL in Ubuntu runs with `secure_file_priv` enabled, which means that you can't just load from (and write to) any file on your system: the file must reside in a particular directory. You can verify that this is the case using this command:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv"
```

You can either turn this setting off (which is a security exposure) or find a way to move your pictures into this directory.